# i get wrong gdp data as error even if i didn't perform any operation on the data python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
 AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-4-c62566676721> in <module>
         15                                       1589942641764.29,1664086754804.89,3542371125827.81,1821872415623.62,
         16                                       2702031788079.47,1134795571930.64,2137439133774.83,1417354966887.42,
    ---> 17                                       485330901134.448,1169431057881.91,2295244758549.53], "Q1: Wrong GDP Data!"
         18 
    
    
    AssertionError: Q1: Wrong GDP Data!
```

I get the above error when I run this code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def answer_one():
    energy = pd.read_excel("Energy Indicators.xls", skiprows=17, header=None, names=['', '', 'Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable'])
    energy = energy.drop(energy.columns[[0, 1]], axis=1)
    energy = energy[:227]
    energy = energy[energy['Country'].notna()]
    energy['Country'] = energy.Country.str.replace("Republic of Korea","South Korea")
    energy['Country'] = energy.Country.str.replace("United States of America","United States")
    energy['Country'] = energy.Country.str.replace("United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland","United Kingdom")
    energy['Country'] = energy.Country.str.replace("China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region","Hong Kong")
    energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.extract('(^[a-zA-Z\s]+)', expand=False).str.strip()
    energy.replace('...', np.nan,inplace = True)
    energy['Energy Supply'] *= 1000000

    GDP = pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv', skiprows=4)
    GDP = GDP[list(GDP.columns[:4]) + list(GDP.columns[-1:-11:-1][::-1])]
    GDP.rename(columns={'Country Name': 'Country'}, inplace=True)
    GDP = GDP[GDP['Country'].notna()]
    GDP.replace({'Country' : { 'Korea, Rep.' : 'South Korea', 'Iran, Islamic Rep.' : 'Iran', 'Hong Kong SAR, China' : 'Hong Kong' }})
    
    ScimEn = pd.read_excel('scimagojr-3.xlsx', nrows=15)
    GDP = GDP[GDP['Country'].isin(ScimEn['Country'])]
    energy = energy[energy['Country'].isin(ScimEn['Country'])]
    f = ScimEn.merge(GDP, on='Country', how='left')
    df = f.merge(energy, on='Country').drop(0)
    gf = df[['Rank', 'Documents', 'Citable documents', 'Citations', 'Self-citations', 'Citations per document', 'H index', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']]
    return gf
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def answer_one():
    energy = pd.read_excel("Energy Indicators.xls", skiprows=17, header=None, names=['', '', 'Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable'])
    energy = energy.drop(energy.columns[[0, 1]], axis=1)
    energy = energy[:227]
    energy = energy[energy['Country'].notna()]
    energy['Country'] = energy.Country.str.replace("Republic of Korea","South Korea")
    energy['Country'] = energy.Country.str.replace("United States of America","United States")
    energy['Country'] = energy.Country.str.replace("United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland","United Kingdom")
    energy['Country'] = energy.Country.str.replace("China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region","Hong Kong")
    energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.extract('(^[a-zA-Z\s]+)', expand=False).str.strip()
    energy.replace('...', np.nan,inplace = True)
    energy['Energy Supply'] *= 1000000

    GDP = pd.read_csv('world_bank.csv', skiprows=4)
    GDP = GDP[list(GDP.columns[:4]) + list(GDP.columns[-1:-11:-1][::-1])]
    GDP.rename(columns={'Country Name': 'Country'}, inplace=True)
    GDP = GDP[GDP['Country'].notna()]
    GDP.replace({'Country' : { 'Korea, Rep.' : 'South Korea', 'Iran, Islamic Rep.' : 'Iran', 'Hong Kong SAR, China' : 'Hong Kong' }})
    
    ScimEn = pd.read_excel('scimagojr-3.xlsx', nrows=15)
    GDP = GDP[GDP['Country'].isin(ScimEn['Country'])]
    energy = energy[energy['Country'].isin(ScimEn['Country'])]
    f = ScimEn.merge(GDP, on='Country', how='left')
    df = f.merge(energy, on='Country').drop(0)
    gf = df[['Rank', 'Documents', 'Citable documents', 'Citations', 'Self-citations', 'Citations per document', 'H index', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']]
    return gf
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your data sources? It would appear that "Q1: Wrong GDP Data!" is an actual string that appeared while reading the GDP data leading to the error.

I assumed you are working with [this GDP dataset for "world_bank.csv"](https://github.com/sidsriv/Introduction-to-Data-Science-in-python/blob/master/world_bank.csv). I downloaded it and ran the second part of your code that reads the .csv as the GDP dataframe, but it worked fine for me. So, either your version of the .csv was bad, or the problem went wrong at the last part when you try to merge it with your other two files, "Energy Indicators.xls" and 'scimagojr-3.xlsx'. Check those files too.